# SQL n:n join over multiple rows

Tags: sql, join, left-join, inner-join

I have a car table that lists various properties and I have a property_group table that combines the various properties into different groups.
Now I want to know which cars fully fit in which property_groups.

With car names unique, this would be a simple join - but with repeating car names ???

car table

| id | name | property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ford | 1 |
| 2 | ford | 2 |
| 3 | nissan | 1 |
| 4 | nissan | 3 |
| 5 | nissan | 5 |

property_group tabe

| id | group | property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | r01 | 1 |
| 2 | r0l | 2 |
| 3 | ks99 | 1 |
| 4 | ks99 | 3 |
| 5 | ks99 | 5 |
| 6 | uv55 | 1 |
| 7 | uv55 | 2 |
| 8 | uv55 | 3 |
| 9 | uv55 | 4 |
| 0 | uv55 | 5 |

expected result:

| name | group |
| --- | --- |
| ford | r01 |
| ford | uv55 |
| nissan | ks99 |
| nissan | uv55 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your results are incorrect.  No car, for instance, has five properties so none match `'uv55'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `join` on the properties and then count how many properties match between the car the group:

```
select c.name, pg.group
from car c join
     (select pg.*,
             count(*) over (partition by group) as num_properties
      from property_group pg
     ) pg
     on pg.property = c.property
group by c.name, pg.group, pg.num_properties
having count(*) = pg.num_properties;
```

Note that `group` is a very poor name for a column, because it is a SQL keyword.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c5615ee7f774751898703b91a63c5059) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: cool, but this only gives me: ford|r01 and 
nissan|ks99
not :
nissan|uv55 and ford|uv55

Comment: @tvmaster . . . I've included a db<>fiddle.  This does what your question is *asking for*.  The results in the question are incorrect.